# Guidance and assurances in flashing Presario CQ62 BIOS in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, laptop, bios

I'm running Ubuntu on an `Compaq Presario CQ62-215DX Notebook PC`. I'm having wireless/suspend issues as described in this [askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365177/hardware-wireless-switch-has-no-effect-after-suspend-and-13-10-upgrade), and after reading the [ubuntu bug reporting page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) I think the solution to my problem is to flash my BIOS.

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` gives an output of: `F.17`, and the newest version of the BIOS available from the HP support site describes itself as `VersionF.29`, so mine is severely outdated.

I downloaded the `sp52598.exe` file from that HP page, and when I `cabextract` it I get this:

```
01444F29.bin
AtpTimerInfo.dll
Ding.wav
FlsHookDll.dll
FlsHook.exe
FWUpdLcl.exe
InsydeFlash.exe
iscflash.dll
iscflash.sys
iscflashx64.sys
platform.ini
xerces-c_2_7.dll
```

I've used unetbootin to create a usb boot stick with freeDOS, (which I believe I formatted as FAT32), put my `spxxxxx.exe` file onto it, and tried to run it, but got:

`This program cannot be run in DOS mode.`

just like [this forum](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/is-it-possible-to-use-hp-winflash-to-upgrade-bios-on-linux-733332/) predicted. That thread then recommends running the `.fd` file within the packed file, but I don't have an `.fd` file, so that thread has dried up for me.

A Ubuntu Bios Update page (I'll post further links in the comments because of my small reputation) suggested making a boot stick of JUST an iso of the `spxxxxx.exe` file, and booting to that, but it didn't do anything for me, just defaulted into Ubuntu, or on more recent tries, Unetbootin just got stuck on it's load page prompting if I wanted the `[default]` boot or not, and pressing enter gets an endless loop.

I've been reading SO MANY PAGES on the process of flashing a BIOS, and it seems there are a thousand ways to do it, and I'm worried about bricking my computer, this thing is my life. This is very uncharted territory, but I must venture in!!! My wireless has to work properly or I can barely get anything done.

I just want guidance and assurances about my particular situation. What's the best way to go here? Any stumbling blocks ahead? Easier ways?

Comment: [The HP product page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=4221035#N1158)

Comment: [An Arch Linux page I'm not sure will apply to me](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux)

Comment: Pages [such as this one](http://www.linuxinsight.com/how-to-flash-motherboard-bios-from-linux-no-dos-windows-no-floppy-drive.html) have so much "greek to me" advice that they're practically worthless.

Comment: Same with pages like [this one](http://www.linuxinsight.com/how-to-flash-motherboard-bios-from-linux-no-dos-windows-no-floppy-drive.html).

Comment: The [ubuntu community bios update page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BiosUpdate). The instructions to get an iso from the `cabextract` command don't even work, so I don't have a lot of confidence in that one.

Answer (score 0):

The executable you've downloaded appears to contain Windows software, and the [HP support page for the download](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-94479-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=4221035&sw_lang=) appears to suggest you should run it under Windows. If that doesn't work, the worst that'll happen is that it won't flash your BIOS; it certainly won't brick your laptop, so you'll lose nothing by trying.

Of course, if you can't boot into Windows, you have a problem. My recommendation there would be to back up your Ubuntu partition to an external drive, then using the system restore discs which probably came with the laptop (and which otherwise can be [ordered, apparently free of charge, from the HP site](https://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/mediaOrder?softwareitem=618088-001&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=4221035&sw_lang=)) to install a fresh copy of Windows in which to perform the BIOS update, and finally wiping the Windows partition, reinstalling Ubuntu, and restoring your backup -- an involved process, to be sure, but if you need the BIOS update that badly, it's probably worthwhile.

Comment: Hm. I'll keep this in mind as a last resort, but if I have to wait for system restore discs (I don't have the originals, I'm not positive I EVER kept them) it won't be a while until I can get to work. I'd like a less invasive solution too.

Comment: I'm thinking I should try to boot into Windows from a usb stick to run the bios flash. Then I wouldn't have to muck with my harddrive, it seems that would be much easier. I'm looking for ways to do that, but can you offer any advice I might not find?

Comment: And going through the process to actually order a recovery disk ends up costing about $15 I must not be under warranty anymore. So I mean it's not ideal. I'll keep working on booting from a usb stick and resort to that if I have to.